# Firebase serve command does not run the entire script code(which in turn should display pages in web app in polymer web app on firebase serve command

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, polymer, firebase-cli, polymer-3.x

Unable to display whole web application while trying to serve polymer web app with firebase serve:
firebase serve

This command only displays part of the code in the browser. It does not run the script command to display the web application pages.

it displays the whole web application when run as npm start in browser

This is my index.html

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2016 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzfddfdfbdfbaSyAcfzb6qhAaw0XzrQXvXB5m-oEVVgPyRfc",
    authDomain: "test-for-autism.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-for-autism.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-for-autism",
    storageBucket: "test-for-autdfdgdfgism.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "446840796343"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>


<!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-functions.js"></script>

<!-- Comment out (or don't include) services that you don't want to use -->
<!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase-storage.js"></script> -->

<script>
  var config = {
    // ...
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>



  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

  <title>TEST FOR AUTISM</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Polymer tfa Demo">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="32x28" href="images/tfa-icon-32.jpg">
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
  <meta name="twitter:site" content="@Polymer">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="tfa">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <style>

    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #FAFAFA;
      color: #383838;
      font-family: Georgia;
      min-height: 100vh;
      -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    /* styling for render while resources are loading */
    tfa-app[unresolved] {
      display: block;
      height: 45px;
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      font-size: 39px;
      font-weight: 600;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    /* mobile */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 15%, rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 30%, rgba(0,0,0,0.7) 48%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 60%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100vh;
      }

      body.fixed-viewport-height {
        background-size: 100% 600px;
      }

      tfa-app[unresolved] {
        height: 22px;
        padding-top: 21px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #FFF; /* --app-cover-text-color */
      }
    }

  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <tfa-app unresolved app-title="TEST FOR AUTISM">L O A D I N G</tfa-app>

  <script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="src/tfa-app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Following is the screenshot:]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to build your app first;

```
npm run build
```

then to preview the build using prpl-server locally:

```
npm run serve
```

Firebase Hosting alone is not sufficient for hosting the prpl-server build since it requires some server-side processing of the user agent string. Instead, you will have to use Firebase Functions for server-side processing. For detailed [instructions](https://gist.github.com/Dabolus/314bd939959ebe68f57f1dcebe120a7e) on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I am getting the foll error on running npm run build:firebase while following the instructions.. Plz help
@HakanC

npm ERR! file /home/nitin/fb/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 1165 while parsing '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse "name": "@polymer/tfa",
npm ERR! JSON.parse "version":'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

Comment: @Daemon , Actually I could not understand the above message. But this two links has all instruction hot to build and deploy app as prpl-server ( This server means: You will have 3 build app, due to your browsers javascript version supports and atomically detect browser support and direct to related app version.) 1 - https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/building-and-deploying#deploying-prpl-server
2. is above Firebase function setup : https://gist.github.com/Dabolus/314bd939959ebe68f57f1dcebe120a7e

Comment: Just to clear the above error. While following the instructions to use Firebase functions for server side processing i get the error :'ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript'. Can you if possible tell me what is causing that error. @HakanC